# Zepto equivalent to jQuery prev([selector])

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, zepto

Does Zepto have an equivalent to jQuery's prev([selector])? I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class='error-placeholder'></span><input type='text' class='email'>
```

In jQuery I would do something like:

```
$('.email').prev('.error-placeholder').text('That email is invalid, Chief.');
```

What's the best way to accomplish this task in Zepto? According to the API, it seems that Zepto's prev() method does not accept a selector parameter, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

EDIT: The example I provided is not ideal. In this case, I could just leave out the selector. But I will be dealing with cases in which there are other elements, and I will need the ability to select a specific one.

Comment: you don't need it to accept a selector parameter. Just leave the selector off.

Comment: Maybe the example I provided wasn't ideal. In this case, you're right; I could just leave out the selector. But I will need to use prev() in other instances where there are other DOM elements in the form.

Comment: In those cases .prev() wouldn't work anyway. .prev() only selects the immediately previous sibling, which is likely why zepto leaves the selector off.

Comment: `.prev()` does appear to be able to take a selector since 1.0. You might be safer doing `.closest('fieldset').find('.error')` if there's any chance that `.error-placeholder` isn't the first previous sibling.

Comment: My understanding is that jQuery's prev() accepts a selector as a parameter. So if an input is preceded by a div, then two spans, you can select the div using prev('div') - even though the div does not immediately precede the input.

Comment: @CodyRomano that is wrong. .prev() Always selects the immediately previous sibling. It then discards that element if it doesn't match the selector. http://jsfiddle.net/5jZmJ/ Note how it logs empty string rather than the text of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zepto has prev()

[From the docs:](http://zeptojs.com/#prev)

prev()  ⇒ collection

prev(selector)  ⇒ collection v1.0+

Get the previous sibling—optionally filtered by selector—of each element in the collection.